# How can i kill docker containers

Tags: docker, container

I have seen many times i am not able to stop conatiner

docker stop hashid

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot stop container 1fdfd212ebb7: no such process
FATA[0000] Error: failed to stop one or more containers
```

when i do `docker ps` then it shows

If i try `docker kill` or `docker rm -f`

then i get this

```
Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container, cannot remove - no such process
FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more containers
```

The only way is to restart docker daemon . i can't do that because my other conatiners are there. i don't want to stop them.

Is there any way to force kill them

Comment: That's quite common issue, what version of docker are you running? You can try latest binaries from [master](https://master.dockerproject.com/), may be it was fixed.

Comment: @キリル hi i think u r right . i have now 1.5 and seems fixed. are you sure it wont happen in these versions

Comment: I was checking this issue on their github [page](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+no+such+process+) and most of issues with similar symptoms have been fixed already, but I can't guarantee that it won't reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue has been fixed in recent releases, you can get latest builds of master branch [here](https://master.dockerproject.com/).

In case of failures, you can check current list of issues and create your own on their [github page](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues?q=).